# Recover data session with relationship in Symfony with twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have a manyToOne relation of my entity ticket to my entity command. I store my tickets and my order in session. I can retrieve the command information by doing for example: {{app.request.session.get("command").Nom}}
**But I can not view the ticket information**. For example, if I want to get the ticket price 107 with twig?

[session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awmGy.png)

Function of my service :

```
public function startCommande(Request $request)
{
    $commande = new Commande();

    $form = $this->form->create(CommandeBilletType::class, $commande);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()){

        $data = $form->getData();
        $this->session->set('commande', $data);
    }
    return $form;

}


public function coordonneesCommande(Request $request)
{
    $commande= $this->session->get('commande');
    $form = $this->form->create(CommandeType::class, $commande);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

            $this->price->tarifBillet($commande);

            $response = new RedirectResponse('paiement');
            $response->send();

    }
   return $form;
}
```

I tried {{app.request.session.get ("commande").Billet().Nom}}
    {{app.request.session.get('Billet.nom')}}

...

Comment: Is billet your ticket object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a collection, you should iterate over it.

First set your "commande".

```
{% set commande = app.session.get('commande') %}
```

Now, you should be able to access the entity information and get your "billets" like this, (if i understand well you have a collection of billet):

```
{% for billet in commande.getBillet() %}
    {{ billet.prix }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask more questions if you need or close the topic by accepting the answer.

Comment: I have another question: I can not access commande.total (as above picture) in session from the controller ? How to do ? thank you